# Angular ngView request Error finding element, Partials not loading

Tags: pug, angularjs-routing, ng-view

I have the following directory structure:

```
Public/
......./js
.........../angularAPP
Views/
....../index.html  //main page with ngView
....../gu.html     //test page to load partial
```

I have routes defined in express but not for the routes which are not referenced by angular (in case that could cause a conflict).

Is the request coming from the views folder? hence the template URL should be `/gu/html`?

Or is it coming from the AngularAPP and should be escaped `../../views/gu.html`?

Where is the request for the partials originating from so that I can provide the correct URL to $routeProvider. I ask because I've tried both and still don't seem to be typing the correct URL. Angular isn't finding the HTML files in the file system, I'm a little lost as to why I can't seem to give the correct route to the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Jade was interrupting the $resource provider. I have the partials populating now and dynamically changing content.

The problem occurred because express routes were coded prior to implementing Angular hence the Express server was requesting Jade render new views. Thus it was interrupting Angular from being able to complete the view look up.

Solution remove routes from project and render the index HTML statically instead of requesting the view via Routes and Jade. All in all Jade and Angular have overlapping functionality, after switching to Angular the page switching and render is IMO more snappy. Also I was defining the routes just fine in Angular config $resource provider.

So for anyone that views this and is wondering why your project might not be rendering the page correctly this could be the issue.